# How to change grub2 keylayout on Samsung laptop

Tags: 16.04

Trying to change grub2 key layout on a Samsung laptop and failing badly.

Created `/etc/grub.d/50_keyboard` file containing

```
 #!/bin/sh
 exec tail -n +3 $0
 # Clavier fr
 insmod keylayouts
 keymap /boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb
```

Edited `/etc/default/grub` file to add

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="at_keyboard"
```

Used command `ckbcomp fr |sudo grub-mklayout -o /boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb` to create the keylayout file

Used command `sudo update-grub` to ensure my changes were written to `/boot`.

Comment: What do you mean "change grub2 key layout"? And the rest of what you're doing makes no sense to me.

Comment: When I press button "a" it writes "q", it should write "a". Nothing obscure as there is official documentation about it https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/grub-mklayout.1.htm‌​l and here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:GRUB2#Custom_keyboard_layout , was able to make this work on numerous machines excluding samsung's offering.

Comment: Since I need to format my response, I'll have to put it into a partial answer... give me a few minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/grub.d/50_keyboard` is incorrect.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# Clavier fr
insmod keylayouts
keymap /boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb
```

The "exec" line is incorrect for your file, but rather than change it or renaming it to 39_keyboard and fixing the exec line...

- delete `/etc/grub.d/50_keyboard`
- edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Add this to the end of this file:

```
insmod keylayouts
keymap /boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb
```

so that the final file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
insmod keylayouts
keymap /boot/grub/layouts/fr.gkb
```

Comment: Why is it incorrect ?

Comment: @Zulgrib The `exec tail` command will force skipping the next three lines.